# Как вывести всплывающее окно через определенное количество времени?

Tags: javascript

Допустим, есть простая страница. Как на ней вывести всплывающее окно, например, через 3 часа после захода на страницу? Если пользователь зашел повторно.

Comment: 1)`setTimeout(функция, пауза в милисекундах)` - максимальная пауза - `2147483647` (чуть больше 24х дней) 2) "Если пользователь зашел повторно"...тут важно 1 условие...если он не залогинен, то никак...можно попробовать в куки написать что то и по этому проверить, но куки можно вытереть.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы понять, был пользователь на сайте или нет, можно создать куки – например, `visit`, и при первом же заходе присвоить ему значение `true`. Таким образом можно определить повторное открытие страницы.

Сделать проверку, был ли пользователь на сайте с помощью следующего условия:

```
if ( $.cookie('visit') == undefined ){
```

Когда пользователь впервые откроет страницу в текущей сессии его браузера, то присвоить ему куки `visit` со значением `true`:

```
$.cookie('visit', true);
```

И уже при повторном открытии страницы выполнить условие.

Открыть окно через определенное время:

```
setTimeout(function() { alert('Окно открыто'); }, 1000); //1000 – это время, равное одной секунде
```